# What does Microsoft SQL Server do?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I understand that this is painfully generic and broad. Nonetheless, all the answers on wikipedia and yahoo (none here that I can find) are pretty useless.

I know T-SQL, C#, etc to some degree. I understand the idea of a database. However, I have NO idea what I created when I made a "server" on my computer through Msft SQL Server. Now I can make databases on that server, and I can connect to them with Visual Studio (sometimes) to use with LINQ or "raw" calls.

Please help me understand (or direct me to an article) of what this myComputerName\SQLEXPRESS (SQL Server xx.x.xxx) thing is. I assume the databases are stored locally...somewhere. SQL Server provides access to the DB files? Why can't they be accessed directly?

Thank you if you even read all this. I really can't narrow the question down.

I guess one specific question is "Can I access the databases without SQL Server running?" Where do I even get the connection string?

Comment: A server is a program that provides access to a resource via a predefined method of communication. That's it. In terms of database server, it provides access to, well, a database (or many databases).  It manages everything (for example security & access control, SQL parsing & query plan caching, data integrity & relation enforcement, binary data file format, its own performance & memory usage, auxiliary tasks like job execution, backups or index maintenance, you name it) so that you can access that database on a high level of abstraction. For example with LINQ or SQL.

Comment: Thank you. Last question - what is the connection string a connection to, the DBMS (the SQL Server...Server instance I created in this case)?

Comment: That depends. Have a look at http://www.connectionstrings.com/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking multiple questions, here.

> However, I have NO idea what I created when I made a "server" on my
>   computer through Msft SQL Server. Now I can make databases on that
>   server, and I can connect to them with Visual Studio (sometimes) to
>   use with LINQ or "raw" calls.
>
> Please help me understand (or direct me to an article) of what this
>   myComputerName\SQLEXPRESS (SQL Server xx.x.xxx) thing is.

The layout of a database server is as follows:

- Server

  - Instance a

    - database aa
    - database ab
    - ...
  - Instance b

    - database ba
    - database bb
    - ...
  - ...

So, when you install MS SQL Server, you install a MS SQL Server "instance". In this "instance", you can create a number databases. Each database has database files, the exact location of these depends on the settings you chose during installation.

> I guess one specific question is "Can I access the databases without
>   SQL Server running?"

You do not usually open dbf(mdf -ldf) files (the database data files) without MS SQL Server, why would you want to ? You should use the backup/restore features inside MS SQL Server.

> Where do I even get the connection string?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for answering despite me asking several questions. One last question - what is the "connection string" to? I know this is like asking "well, what is an API address a connection request to?" but I think that can be answered with something simple like "Well, it's a GET/PUT/etc request to the server, over the internet, or the http protocol." So, I am asking for a very simple answer like that, not in depth. Separate question btw, if you feel like it, you answered my initial ones, ty again.

Comment: Your program needs access to database tables, for example, to be able to execute a query against a database, you must connect to the instance/database. The connect string is like an internet URL (http://www.google.com:80/somePage), comprised of host, port, database name (for example). In C#, you specify a data source (SQLEXPRESS, your instance name) and a database name, MyDB. You can optionally specify connection parameters.

[Timeout during comment edit.]

Answer (score 0):

The "server" is a process/service running on your computer which can be connected to over the network and provides the API to access your database.

"Why can't they be accessed directly?" Is like asking why do I need Word to view Word files, can't I use Notepad for that. Sure you can, but not really.

Another reason is - imagine multiple processes need to access the database. If each reads and writes to the same files, something WILL break if they don't coordinate. Having a separate server process encapsulates all this.

"Can I access the databases without SQL server running?" I mean yes but actually no.

If you want a database that your program accesses directly (or let's say, your program is also the database server in a sense) - then you can use sqlite, or for simple tasks there are also ODBC drivers for CSV, so you can use CSV files as if they were a database. A dedicated SQL server is always better for bigger more complex tasks and data models though.